# Clarification about LINQ and how to correctly load a Table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Assume I have 2 tables:

**TableA:**, columns: A_ID, B_ID

**TableB:**, columns: B_ID

According to the model diagram I have under TableA the A_ID column and NavigationProperty of B which looks like only a reference to B. (maybe since it's a FK?)

What bothers me now is that once I load the context.TableA.ToList() rows
and I try to iterate the items in this list, I don't have access to the simple column B_ID but I only have B, and once doing item.B.ID I get a null reference.

code sample:

```
List<TableA> items = context.TableA.ToList();

foreach(TableA item in items)
{
    item.B.ID <- null reference.
}
```

I know this is probably the idea behind LINQ but I think my approach is wrong. Could anyone
please explain how I can correctly load the entire table with its columns? And how these principles of LINQ are reflected in my example?

Please provide code samples :)

Comment: So, If I understand well: B is not null while iterating through the collection of A's, but B.ID is null? Clearly the ID property (it *is* a property, isn't it?) is not the primary key of B then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in chat, Entity Framework syntax has changed, and keeping up to date, with the current Entity Framework 5 will ensure that examples listed on various pages stay relevant.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) may give you the solution.

You need to eagerly load the related entities.

Comment: I have just read it, i feel really confused now. U say i should explicitly load these entities but: 1. the eagerly loading makes more sense to me. 2. i even tried the eagerly loading but im unable to do this operation ".Include(b => b.MyTable)", i get an lambda expression error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type". 3. Last, I tried the Explicitly Loading but i'm unable to access the Entry property. feels like a mess now :(

Comment: @Popokoko, your include statement doesn't sound right, it should be something like `.Include(a => a.B)` or `.Include("TableB")`... most people prefer the first, strongly typed version when possible.  The second version is brittle, if the class names change, for example.

Comment: Mainly, i don't have any intelli-sense over the "a." you just wrote, so any string ill write won't compile for me. it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Popokoko hmm, can you post the entire linq statement you have tried into your question?

Comment: context.Categories.Include(x => x.Icons);

Comment: @Popokoko I made a chat room if you want to try to discuss this... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35671/entity-framework-linq-clarification

Comment: @Popokoko Sorry I meant you need to eagerly load them, I edited my answer.